# Android - MediaPlayer : How to separating fastForward to another method (that later will be call)?

Tags: java, android, methods, android-mediaplayer

Here's my snippets :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private int seekForwardTime = 5000;
private int seekBackwardTime = 5000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    seekForward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Seek Forward music", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            forwardSong(mediaPlayer);
        }
    });
}

public void forwardSong(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    int currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    String tag2 = "currentPosition";
    Log.v(tag2, String.valueOf(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()));
    if (currentPosition + seekForwardTime <= mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()) {
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(currentPosition + seekForwardTime);
    } else {
        String tag = "main activity";
        Log.v(tag, "else state");
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
    }
}
```

}

As per title, I want to separate Fast Forward (seek 5 second forward for each press) behavior from seekForward.OnClickListener to another method (forwardSong).

But, when I trigger seekForward, instead of seeking, it kills mediaPlayer. So I have to press 'play' button again and start from beginning of song.

Am I missed something? I'm happy to receive any solution and/or advice.

*ps : please ignore the Log statement, I'm just do some test before.*

Thanks!

---

Edit - 09/08/2017

As requested, here's the logcat

```
08-09 16:36:01.688 2707-2707/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
08-09 16:36:01.688 2707-2707/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
08-09 16:36:01.781 2707-2707/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.android.musicplayer-2/lib/x86
08-09 16:36:01.791 2707-2707/? I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
08-09 16:36:01.856 2707-2707/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
08-09 16:36:02.094 2707-2707/com.example.android.musicplayer D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
08-09 16:36:02.189 2707-2730/com.example.android.musicplayer I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
08-09 16:36:02.189 2707-2730/com.example.android.musicplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
08-09 16:36:02.189 2707-2730/com.example.android.musicplayer W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
08-09 16:36:02.189 2707-2730/com.example.android.musicplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
08-09 16:36:02.219 2707-2730/com.example.android.musicplayer D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xa1328e80: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
08-09 16:36:02.264 2707-2730/com.example.android.musicplayer D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa1328e80: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa1320a20)
08-09 16:36:02.333 2707-2707/com.example.android.musicplayer W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
08-09 16:36:02.343 2707-2730/com.example.android.musicplayer D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa1328e80: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa1320a20)
08-09 16:58:47.717 2707-2730/com.example.android.musicplayer D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa1328e80: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa1320a20)
08-09 16:58:47.747 2707-2730/com.example.android.musicplayer D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa1328e80: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa1320a20)
08-09 16:58:48.672 2707-2707/com.example.android.musicplayer V/currentPosition: 707
08-09 16:58:48.673 2707-2707/com.example.android.musicplayer V/main activity: else state
08-09 16:58:49.669 2707-2730/com.example.android.musicplayer D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa1328e80: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa1320a20)
08-09 16:58:50.684 2707-2730/com.example.android.musicplayer D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa1328e80: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa1320a20)
08-09 16:58:51.667 2707-2730/com.example.android.musicplayer D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa1328e80: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa1320a20)
08-09 16:58:53.631 2707-2730/com.example.android.musicplayer D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa1328e80: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa1320a20)
```

I'm confused. Why it entering else statement?

Comment: Post your logcat.

Comment: @aborocz Ok added. Please check again my post.

Comment: Your logcat was not necessary. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `forwardSong` function the following way :

```
public void forwardSong(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    int currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    String tag2 = "currentPosition";
    Log.v(tag2, String.valueOf(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()));
    if (currentPosition + seekForwardTime <= mediaPlayer.getDuration()) {
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(currentPosition + seekForwardTime);
    } else {
        String tag = "main activity";
        Log.v(tag, "else state");
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
    }
}
```

The following condition is the problem, it will be always false and the `mediaplayer` will always seek to the end of your media file because of your else statement.

```
if (currentPosition + seekForwardTime <= mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition())
```

Comment: yeah.I'm notice it also from Log. But, why it entering else statement?
Any advice for if condition? or I must to use another method on if condition?

Comment: I already posted the solution for the if statement. `if (currentPosition + seekForwardTime <= mediaPlayer.getDuration()) {`

Comment: Ah sorry. I didn't pay attention to that line